# What machine used POKE for printing?

Tags: basic, identify-this-computer

I was looking through the Super Star Trek code when I noticed this for the first time:

```
7540 REM INPUT"DO YOU WANT A HARDCOPY? IS THE TTY ON (Y/N)";A$
7542 REM IFA$="Y"THENPOKE1229,2:POKE1237,3:NULL1
```

Those `POKE`s... anyone have an idea what system they may have been for? I believe this version was written on a Nova, but I wouldn't have imagined it used pokes for I/O.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was for Microsoft 8K BASIC for Altair.

You're right that Nova BASIC didn't/wouldn't use `POKE`: it wasn't a keyword in either Single User BASIC (1970) or the later Extended BASIC. But [Basic Computer Games Microcomputer Edition](https://archive.org/details/Basic_Computer_Games_Microcomputer_Edition_1978_Creative_Computing/page/n172/mode/1up?q=star+trek) on page 158 says it was written on a DG Nova 800 …

On the [next page](https://archive.org/details/Basic_Computer_Games_Microcomputer_Edition_1978_Creative_Computing/page/n173/mode/1up?q=star%20trek), though, the program listing states:

```
180 REM *** CONVERTED TO MICROSOFT 8 K BASIC 3/16/78 BY JOHN BORDERS
```

I can't find a list of handy pokes for Altair BASIC, but they must've been out there at some time.

Comment: Ah, I did not clue to MS being Altair in particular, but in retrospect...